# How to change the transparency of the data points in scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am plotting a scatterplot but I want stroke points = 1 overlap stroke points = 0 as you can see from the plot it is very difficult to analyse stroke. Would appreciate the help on this problem.

I used the following code to achieve the plot :

```
sns.scatterplot(x = df.Age, y=df.Bmi, hue = df.Stroke)
```

[Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqcL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alpha`

```py
ALPHA = 0.5
sns.scatterplot(x=df.Age, y=df.Bmi, hue=df.Stroke, alpha=ALPHA)
```

This would make the all dots "half-visible" so you can distinguish them better.

Comment: I did that but the orange points are difficult to see. I just want the orange points more visible than blue points.